# Android : find WebView create Print Document Adapter source code

Tags: android, printing, webview

I use this code to print html based pages in android:

```
PrintDocumentAdapter printAdapter = webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter();
```

Now I want to write my own `PrintDocumentAdapter` using html based views so I want to know how `WebView` works to generate a `PrintDocumentAdapter`. Where can I find the code? in Android Studio I use Ctrl+B to jump to declaration but cannot find the code which render html to PrintDocumentAdapter. I explore `WebView.java` too.
update:
I write my own `PrintDocumentAdapter` draw views on canvas, but the result is not satisfying so I decide to use html. printing html by `WebView` doesn't care about page breaks. so I want to add content to webview pace by pace and measure height, if webview height is greater than page height go to next page, so I need to know how draw webview on canvas in a `PrintDocumentAdapter`.

Comment: I suspect that a lot of that code will be in Blink and Chromium.

Comment: have you any link of them? how can I use them in android?